# WPF ListView comsumed focus of autocomplete Textbox as textbox is its ItemsTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf

Let me take a simple demo Friend class:

```
public class Friend
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have static array of friends for DataBinding.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window,INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public static Friend[] Friends { get; set; } = new Friend[]
    {
            new Friend(){Name="Adam" },
            new Friend(){Name="Betty" },
            new Friend(){Name="Cate" },
    };

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textbox = sender as TextBox;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(textbox, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(textbox.Text)));
    }
}
```

After that I put friends's name in ListView with TextBox as ItemsTemplate to edit friend's name

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Static local:MainWindow.Friends }" Width="200">
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"  Value="Stretch"></Setter>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name ,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Method `TextBox_TextChanged` fires `PropertyChanged` on `Text` property. Combining with `UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged` gives textbox ability to autocomplete or in other words updating source as I type. The default behavior is when lost focus.

The setup works nicely when textbox stands alone. But when I put it in DataTemplate, problem occurs. As I change text, the focus pops into ListView. Unless I click on the textbox, I can't find a way to regain Keyboard focus on textbox.

I have tried `textbox.Focus()`, `Keyboard.Focus(textbox)`. All of them failed.

- Why does the focus pop into ListView?
- Is there any way to prevent that?
- Why can't I change the keyboard focus back to Textbox?

Update 1: this is a simple example from my project. In my project, I have 2 `ObservableCollection<double>` of X and Y coordinate. I want to geometry data update as I type in the Textbox.

Comment: What's your expected behaviour? I didn't see the necessity for using `TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"` and `INotifyPropertyChanged` for `MainWindow`.

Comment: Let say it's not a string of name but a coordinate of point. I want to change geometry as I type in the textbox.

Comment: In my project, there are 2 ways to change geometry. One is from textbox, two is from canvas. Both ways are connected into GeometryViewModel. And the `INotifyPropertyChanged` is implemented there.

Comment: `TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"` calls for `PropertyChanged` then later invoke on `Text` property in other to update binding source as I type. And in this example, to have `PropertyChanged` I have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on `MainWindow`